# Rails: Cannot load such file -- ordrin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, rubygems

I am still new to development using Rails, and have followed various tutorials. I want to create a simple application using the Ordrin API. I have been stuck at a minute problem for a long time.

Using the [Ordrin API](https://github.com/ordrin/api-ruby#installation) makes use of the line:

```
require 'ordrin'
```

However, the view related to the controller this occurs in shows the following error.

```
cannot load such file -- ordrin
```

Even though I have installed the gem earlier using

```
gem install ordrin
```

I have tried using the complete path for the gem returned by the command

```
gem which ordrin
```

But then I get an error `cannot load such file -- json-schema`, which is apparently a dependancy for ordrin.

How do I make the require statement load the default gem as managed by RubyGems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following line in your gem file and try

```
gem 'ordrin'
```

and don't forget to run the following command

```
bundle install
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! So, if I just write `gem 'ordrin'` in the gemfile, and run the `bundle install` command, it will install automatically?

Comment: Yes, it will install and make it available to your application